# Call API only when data changes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an endpoint which I use logic App in Azure to make an Rest API call once a day and this creates a JSON file and this places it into a designated blob storage but 
now I would like to make an API call when there is a change within the Web API. Is there a way to only make a call when there is a change in the data using Azure.

Comment: So, the Logic App create a json file. When it is there and some time after this file has been created it can be changed and *than* you want to call an API. Is this assumption correct? What process changes the data?

Comment: The Logic App makes a Web API call once a day and creates a JSON file but now I want to make an API call when there is a change. There is a website which captures train status i.e delay or good service etc and this status can change time to time. I hope this make sense.

Comment: no it doesnt make sense. you are creating a json file, and now want to know if there are changes to the data. what 2 data sets are you comparing? we just know about 1 json file, we dont know what it looks like and what you are comparing that 1 json file to

Comment: If there are changes within the API I want to be able to make another call automatically. The API tends to change frequently and sometimes it doesn't. I just want to make the API call when the data within the API changes.